# Windows FTP Server: No ftp-data flow from server after client receiving response code 125

Tags: windows, ftp

On Windows 8.1, we're using the default FTP Server for file transferring. After establishing the FTP connection from the client, i.e. CWD, TYPE I, PASV, SYN/[SYN,ACK]/ACK, SIZE, RETR, etc. the server responded with code 125 to indicate transfer starting. However, after that, there was no FTP Data sent from server to the client. After sometime, the server timed out (error code 550) on the file transfer. Immediately after this failure, there was another file transfer between the client and server and it was successful. When successful, there will be FTP Data going through from server to the client. For the whole situation, there were multiple clients were attempting to download same set of files at the same time from the server. But the number of the clients were only a few and should not exceed the concurrent connection limit.

My question is: why the server not sending the data when everything is set and ready? Thanks for your helps!

Comment: Did you set firewall as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/a/722610/269373)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this particular situation, the firewall on the machine of the FTP server was off. So, there should be no firewall issue.

Comment: That link discusses firewall rules required for the *client* not the server (it just happens in that case the client was a server OS).

Comment: I forgot to mention that immediately this timeout, there was another file transfer between this client and the server and it was successful. I've modified the original post to include more information.